# Elementary probability theory and its set-theoretic aspects

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Since the publication of Kolmogorov's *Foundations of the theory of probability* in 1933, all the concepts of the theory have been redefined in a set-theoretic framework (events, probability as a function on the set of subsets of a universe $\Omega$, ...). In particular, the *logic* of events has become the *algebra* of subsets of $\Omega$.

However, in the elementary applications of the theory (like the ones taught in schools), are these set-theoretic aspects necessary ?

Do you see an exercise where the set-theoretic machinery is necessary, or at least very useful, to get to the solution ?

Comment: A light hearted comment: doing probability theory without measure theory is like having a building without a foundation!

Comment: Already the formula of total probability is much clearer if you draw $\Omega$ and your partition, and in fact students are used to consider set-theoretic facts to gather intuitions on a problem from a young age.

Comment: "Taught in schools" ...which schools?  :)  Venn diagrams and partitions are surely "very useful" in any elementary problems (up to highschool level), but the more advanced stuff I'd think arent necessary as long as the sample space is finite.  Once you run into infinite / continuous space you might need a good foundation, or else you end up wasting time arguing about "paradoxes" (conditioning on an event of prob 0, en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability), en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox etc)